# I am trying to figure out how someone had done their two-way ANOVA test and can't get the same results they did. I'm inputting it incorrectly perhaps?

Tags: anova, biostatistics

Here are the correct results:

[image: Correct Results]

Here is how I inputted it into Excel (Note: I believed they used SPSS)

[image: My results]

Comment: Where do the data and the analysis you want to reproduce come from? Please provide a reference and some context to make this question more complete. Also, it is not helpful to post (only) an image of code/data/errors; see [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9566484). To make it easier to get help, provide the data as in a text (table) format.

Comment: The data comes from an IB student's biology extended essay that was published on that student's website, for which they received a 31/34. I am trying to reproduce the data in order to know how to carry out the test on my own data. As for tabulating the data on here, I'm struggling quite a bit to figure that out since it's a lot to include.

Comment: I would want to check those results also. You're using Excel (and I see that you've already gotten the advice that you won't get far doing statistical analysis with Excel). It should be possible to save the data spreadsheet as a tab or comma separated file (.txt or .csv) & copy-paste in your question.